# TeacherId cannot have two records equals

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I'm developing a applicattion in c# and I'm doing a form where I can add for each teacher which class and course he will have, but I don't want the user, for the same teacher, to be allowed to add twice or more the same class, thus creating duplicate records unnecessarily, I tried one query on my code to verify that class already was assigned to the teacher selected.

The structure of the table is:

- ProfessoresTurmas: Name of the table;
- Id: ID of each record, Primary Key;
- ProfessorId: Teacher's ID, Foreign Key from Teachers table;
- ProfessorNome: Teacher's Name;
- CursoId: Course's Id, Foreign Key from Courses Table;
- CursoNome: Course's Name;
- TurmaId: Classe's Id, Foreign Key from Classes Table;
- TurmaNome: Classe's Name;

This is the code I've tried:

```
----------------------------Part of the code to do the verification-------------------------
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand check_Class_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(TurmaNome) FROM ProfessorTurmas WHERE ProfessorNome = @ProfessorNome", Con);
    check_Class_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfessorNome", textBox_NameTeacher.Text);
    int ClassExists = (int)check_Class_Name.ExecuteScalar();
    Con.Close();

    else if(ClassExists > 0)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
            Con.Close();
            return;
         }
    else
-----------------From here is the code to insert the record into the table------------------
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.adicionarTurmasProfessores(combobox_IdTeacher.SelectedValue.ToString(), textBox_NameTeacher.Text, comboBox_IdCurso.SelectedValue.ToString(), textBox_NameCurso.Text, combobox_IdTurma.SelectedValue.ToString(), textBox_NameTurma.Text);
                        MessageBox.Show("Registo Adicionado!");
                        DisplayTeachers();
                        Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        if (gender == "Masculino")
                        {
                            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("O professor " + textBox_NameTeacher.Text + " já pertence a essa turma! \nPretende ver a mensagem de erro completa?", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                MainClass.ShowMSG(Ex.Message, "Error...", "Error");
                                Con.Close();
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Con.Close();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("A professora " + textBox_NameTeacher.Text + " já pertence a essa turma! \nPretende ver a mensagem de erro completa?", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                MainClass.ShowMSG(Ex.Message, "Error...", "Error");
                                Con.Close();
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Con.Close();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[Image of design Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk4VY.png)

[Image of the form to insert teacher's records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk3qY.png)

The problem of this code is when I try to add, for example, to Teacher1 Class1, and that record already exists, pop up error message, but if I try to add Teacher1 Class1 and already exists a different teacher assigned with Class1 it pop up error message as well, and I dont want to make the class column unique, I just want to verify if Teacher1 has already Class1.

[Image of the error that is not supposed to pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsk2Q.png)

If you can suggest a query that make that function, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Add a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in the SQL for this purpose.

Comment: I explained, that if I add Primary Key or Unique Key one class cannot be inserted twice in the table, and i dont want that, I want that one teacher cannot have the same class twice on my table

Comment: Then use a TRIGGER

Comment: Whats a TRIGGER?

Comment: Please provide foreign tables (show). Right in question

Comment: @McNets using triggers in SQL is a bad practice, you slit logic between two logical part of your service. Don't use it.

Comment: @hamaronooo triggers are useful if you use it properly, but for this case a simple constraint will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a composite primary key: a primary key made up of two or more attributes.

You should use both the teacher Id and class Id as the primary key.

Example SQL for the key definition:

PRIMARY KEY (ProfessorId, TurmaId).